# How to store multiple secrets in AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have following requirements to store multiple Secret/Key value (around 200 secrets) in AWS Secrets Manager and I do not want to enter each and every secret key/value manually from AWS Secrets Manager console. Although I have researched a bit and found from AWS docs that I can create a `JSON` file where I can write all Secret Key/Value and then pass that file to AWS Secrets manager command:

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret --name MyTestDatabaseSecret \
--description "My test database secret created with the CLI" \
--secret-string file://mycreds.json
```

Is this a good way of doing this or can there be any other better way to store all these secrets all at once?

Comment: I think this is the better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

testing in my AWS account this works like a charm:

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret --name TestMultiplesValues4 --description "Mytest with multiples values" --secret-string file://secretmanagervalues.json
```

Then the json file will be:

```
{"Juan":"1","Pedro":"2","Pipe":"3"}
```

where Juan is the key #1 and 1 the secret value of that key...

It is very simple and easy,

**Note**: *this is to create one secret manager with multiples key/Value pair, not to create multiples secret managers with one Key/Value each one. Be careful with this concept.*

Hope this help you more.